# Error when registering Event Log on Windows for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm running PostgreSQL 10 on Windows Server 2016. I would like to log to the Windows Event Log. When I register pgevent.dll as instructed in section [18.11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/event-log-registration.html) of the documentation, I get an error:

> The module "d:\PostgreSQL\pg10\lib\postgresql\pgevent.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.
>   Make sure that "d:\PostgreSQL\pg10\lib\postgresql\pgevent.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

I think I'm using the correct pgevent.dll file, but can't figure out why regsvr32 can't get it registered. I am using a command prompt for the command that is "Run As Administrator".

Comment: Are you using the 64-bit version of `regsvr32` with 64-bit PostgreSQL binaries on a 64-bit operating system?

Comment: I tried the 64-bit version of regsvr32 and got the same error.